# How to create generic JSON serializer/deserializer in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, jackson, json4s

I wanted to serialize and deserialize some case classes and realized I was repeating code. Unfortunately I cannot figure out a way to keep things DRY. Hoping someone can provide some assistance. Below I will provide a sample problem that is not DRY.

#### Sample Problem

```
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization

import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

import org.json4s.JsonAST.JString
import org.json4s.{CustomSerializer, DefaultFormats}


case class Bar(bar: String, date: ZonedDateTime)
case class Foo(foo: String)

trait JsonParser {
  private case object ZDTSerializer extends CustomSerializer[ZonedDateTime](_ => (
    { case JString(s) => ZonedDateTime.parse(s) },
    { case zdt: ZonedDateTime => JString(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"))) }
  ))

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + ZDTSerializer
}

object BarParser extends JsonParser {
  def deserialize(jsonBar: String): Bar = {
    Serialization.read[Bar](jsonBar)
  }

  def serialize(bar: Bar): String = {
    Serialization.write[Bar](bar)
  }
}

object FooParser extends JsonParser {
  def deserialize(jsonFoo: String): Foo = {
    Serialization.read[Foo](jsonFoo)
  }

  def serialize(foo: Foo): String = {
    Serialization.write[Foo](foo)
  }
}



object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val foo = Foo("foo")
    println(FooParser.serialize(foo)) // {"foo":"foo"}
    println(FooParser.deserialize(FooParser.serialize(foo))) // Foo(foo)
  }
}
```

Above it is clear that the logic to serialize and deserialize is repeated. This is one of the things I've tried (which doesn't compile).

#### Attempt to Solve

```
case class Bar(product: String, date: ZonedDateTime)
case class Foo(title: String)

abstract class GenericJsonParser[T] {
  private case object ZDTSerializer extends CustomSerializer[ZonedDateTime](_ => (
    { case JString(s) => ZonedDateTime.parse(s) },
    { case zdt: ZonedDateTime => JString(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"))) }
  ))

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + ZDTSerializer

  def deserialize(json: String): T = {
    Serialization.read[T](json)  // No Manifest available for T
  }

  def serialize(thing: T): String = {
    Serialization.write[T](thing) // type arguments [A] conform to the bounds of none of the overloaded alternatives ...
  }
}

object BarJsonParser extends GenericJsonParser[Bar]

object FooParser extends GenericJsonParser[Foo]
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jackson, but you should be able to solve the "No manifest available" error simply by adding a context bound at the definition of `T`: `abstract class GenericJsonParser[T: Manifest]`.

Comment: Hi @BrianMcCutchon thanks for the help. I should listen to the compiler better. I solved by using `abstract class GenericJsonParser[A <: AnyRef](implicit m: Manifest[A])`. Hoping you can help clarify why this is needed. My understanding is `Manifest[A]` is required because the type of A is required to be known at runtime. `Manifest[A]` prevents the type from being erased from erasure. `AnyRef` looks like like the root of all reference types, but in Scala everything. So what would be an `Any` but not an `AnyRef`? The errors seem like something compiler should take care of.

Comment: @mtjandra, yes I expect you need `Manifest` because Java implements generics via type erasure, but the JSON library needs to know actual type to know how to serialize/deserialize it.  AFAIU `Manifest` doesn't stop type erasure, it just passes type info as one more (implicit) argument. As for `AnyRef` vs `Any` you can find some details [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html). "_`Any` has two direct subclasses: `AnyVal` and `AnyRef`. `AnyVal` represents value types._ " So `AnyVal` is things like `Int` or `Boolean` which are not `AnyRef` (which is essentially Java `Object`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Json.format[ACaseClass], for example:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Format, Json}
case class ACaseClass(value: String, anotherValue: Int)
implicit val formatACaseClass = Json.format[ACaseClass]
```

I guess for Seralization.read and write you still have to pass an implicit value, jvm need must know how to read/write your object/

Comment: It should be noted that this requires adding [Play Json](https://github.com/playframework/play-json) as a dependency if you aren't already using Play.

Comment: Hi @user3101247. Unfortunately I'm not using Play. Regardless I'm not too sure what you are achieving here. Seems like you are explicitly saying serialize/deserialize from `ACaseClass`. This is a concrete case class and not a generic.

Comment: I am confused, do you want to create a Generic parser for all classes? If it that is the case don't you think you are trying to "reinvent the wheel". I am not sure what library you are using, but it should be able to serialize/deserialize all basic classes, other than that you need to give a hint of what you are trying to do, "Json.format" can infer that from "case classes", so if you want to do something similar then take a look to play source code.